# Symfony 3 programming ManyToMany Options loading from a database

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I´m new to symfony and very frustrated on a problem. I want program a Personal search site. A Project (for example called "Search Call-Center Agents)" have many Softskills that the new worker must have. I have a many to many Doctrine connection in my database and want to load the options in the Table Softskill in my form, but it doesnt´t work.

My FormType ProductType

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('jobgroup')
        ->add('section')
        ->add('projecttype')
        ->add('firmtype')
        ->add('status')
        ->add('creater')
        ->add('advisor')
        ->add('creatdate', DateType::class)
        ->add('createannounce')
        ->add('createfrido')
        ->add('place')
        ->add('zip')
        ->add('pkw')
        ->add('oepnv')
        ->add('jobtype')
        ->add('takeover')
        ->add('presentationtype')
        ->add('reward')
        ->add('perks')
        ->add('vma')
        ->add('drivemoney')
        ->add('perks2')
        ->add('tasksection')
        ->add('qualification')
        ->add('worktime')
        ->add('softskills', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => SoftskillType::class,
            'allow_add' => true
                ))

        ->add('workmodels', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => WorkmodelType::class,
            'allow_add' => true))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;





}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Project',
    ));
}
}
```

My FormType for Softskills

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SoftskillType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Softskill',
    ));
}
}
```

My Project Class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 */
class Project
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->softskills = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->workmodels = new ArrayCollection();
}
public function addSoftskill(Softskill $softskill)
{
    $this->softskill->add($softskill);
}

public function removeSoftskill(Softskill $softskill)
{
    $this->softskill->add($softskill);
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $jobgroup;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $section;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $projecttype;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $firmtype;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $creater;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $advisor;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $creatdate;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $createannounce;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $createfrido;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $place;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $zip;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $pkw;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $oepnv;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $jobtype;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $takeover;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $presentationtype;

//Vergütung
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $reward;

//Zulagen
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $perks;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $vma;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $drivemoney;

//übertarifliche Zulagen
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $perks2;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $worktime;


//Arbeitszeitmodell
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Workmodel")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="workmodel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $workmodel;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $tasksection;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $qualification;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Softskill")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="softskill_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $softskill;

public function __toString() {
return $this->name;
```

}

```
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set jobgroup
 *
 * @param string $jobgroup
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setJobgroup($jobgroup)
{
    $this->jobgroup = $jobgroup;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get jobgroup
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getJobgroup()
{
    return $this->jobgroup;
}

/**
 * Set section
 *
 * @param string $section
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setSection($section)
{
    $this->section = $section;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get section
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSection()
{
    return $this->section;
}

/**
 * Set projecttype
 *
 * @param string $projecttype
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setProjecttype($projecttype)
{
    $this->projecttype = $projecttype;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get projecttype
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProjecttype()
{
    return $this->projecttype;
}

/**
 * Set firmtype
 *
 * @param string $firmtype
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setFirmtype($firmtype)
{
    $this->firmtype = $firmtype;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get firmtype
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirmtype()
{
    return $this->firmtype;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param boolean $status
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set creater
 *
 * @param string $creater
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setCreater($creater)
{
    $this->creater = $creater;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get creater
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCreater()
{
    return $this->creater;
}

/**
 * Set advisor
 *
 * @param string $advisor
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setAdvisor($advisor)
{
    $this->advisor = $advisor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get advisor
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAdvisor()
{
    return $this->advisor;
}

/**
 * Set creatdate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $creatdate
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setCreatdate($creatdate)
{
    $this->creatdate = $creatdate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get creatdate
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreatdate()
{
    return $this->creatdate;
}

/**
 * Set createannounce
 *
 * @param boolean $createannounce
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setCreateannounce($createannounce)
{
    $this->createannounce = $createannounce;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createannounce
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getCreateannounce()
{
    return $this->createannounce;
}

/**
 * Set createfrido
 *
 * @param boolean $createfrido
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setCreatefrido($createfrido)
{
    $this->createfrido = $createfrido;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createfrido
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getCreatefrido()
{
    return $this->createfrido;
}

/**
 * Set place
 *
 * @param string $place
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setPlace($place)
{
    $this->place = $place;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get place
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlace()
{
    return $this->place;
}

/**
 * Set zip
 *
 * @param string $zip
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setZip($zip)
{
    $this->zip = $zip;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get zip
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getZip()
{
    return $this->zip;
}

/**
 * Set pkw
 *
 * @param boolean $pkw
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setPkw($pkw)
{
    $this->pkw = $pkw;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get pkw
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getPkw()
{
    return $this->pkw;
}

/**
 * Set oepnv
 *
 * @param boolean $oepnv
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setOepnv($oepnv)
{
    $this->oepnv = $oepnv;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get oepnv
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getOepnv()
{
    return $this->oepnv;
}

/**
 * Set jobtype
 *
 * @param string $jobtype
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setJobtype($jobtype)
{
    $this->jobtype = $jobtype;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get jobtype
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getJobtype()
{
    return $this->jobtype;
}

/**
 * Set takeover
 *
 * @param string $takeover
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setTakeover($takeover)
{
    $this->takeover = $takeover;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get takeover
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTakeover()
{
    return $this->takeover;
}

/**
 * Set presentationtype
 *
 * @param string $presentationtype
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setPresentationtype($presentationtype)
{
    $this->presentationtype = $presentationtype;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get presentationtype
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPresentationtype()
{
    return $this->presentationtype;
}

/**
 * Set reward
 *
 * @param string $reward
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setReward($reward)
{
    $this->reward = $reward;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get reward
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReward()
{
    return $this->reward;
}

/**
 * Set perks
 *
 * @param string $perks
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setPerks($perks)
{
    $this->perks = $perks;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get perks
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPerks()
{
    return $this->perks;
}

/**
 * Set vma
 *
 * @param string $vma
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setVma($vma)
{
    $this->vma = $vma;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get vma
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getVma()
{
    return $this->vma;
}

/**
 * Set drivemoney
 *
 * @param string $drivemoney
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setDrivemoney($drivemoney)
{
    $this->drivemoney = $drivemoney;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get drivemoney
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDrivemoney()
{
    return $this->drivemoney;
}

/**
 * Set perks2
 *
 * @param string $perks2
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setPerks2($perks2)
{
    $this->perks2 = $perks2;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get perks2
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPerks2()
{
    return $this->perks2;
}

/**
 * Set tasksection
 *
 * @param string $tasksection
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setTasksection($tasksection)
{
    $this->tasksection = $tasksection;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tasksection
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTasksection()
{
    return $this->tasksection;
}

/**
 * Set qualification
 *
 * @param string $qualification
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setQualification($qualification)
{
    $this->qualification = $qualification;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get qualification
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQualification()
{
    return $this->qualification;
}

/**
 * Set worktime
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Worktime $worktime
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setWorktime(\AppBundle\Entity\Worktime $worktime = null)
{
    $this->worktime = $worktime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get worktime
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Worktime
 */
public function getWorktime()
{
    return $this->worktime;
}

/**
 * Set workmodel
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Workmodel $workmodel
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setWorkmodel(\AppBundle\Entity\Workmodel $workmodel = null)
{
    $this->workmodel = $workmodel;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get workmodel
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Workmodel
 */
public function getWorkmodel()
{
    return $this->workmodel;
}

/**
 * Set softskill
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Softskill $softskill
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setSoftskill(\AppBundle\Entity\Softskill $softskill = null)
{
    $this->softskill = $softskill;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get softskill
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Softskill
 */
public function getSoftskill()
{
    return $this->softskill;
}
}
```

Can someone please tell me what i have forgotten? If i make a for loop to map the form.softskill, no values appear on the form.

Comment: On a first glance: `Project::removeSoftskill()` does `$this->softskill->add($softskill);`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, its a copy paste failure, but did not solve my problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I can see where is mapped your m2m relation. Can you explicit it ?

Comment: The m2m relation ist between project and softskill (project -> project_softskill <- softskill). In the table softskill are the data (kindly for example) that should be listed in my form as a many checkbox to check a multiple choice or one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s solved, i have a mistake in the formular builder. You can use multiple choices in an Entity Class. I was a little bit confused about this in the past :)

Thanks to all for your anwsers and comments.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should try another *$softskill* annotation

Maybe you need annotation like in p. **5.9. Many-To-Many, Bidirectional** in the link below.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13729507)

Comment: This is official doc: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html